# C# How to communicate between 2 servers

Tags: c#, server-to-server

I have a website running ASP.NET (C#) on `server A`. I need my website to access a webservice on `server B`. `server B` will only accept incoming requests if the requestee is located within a certain IP range and `server A` is not within this range.

I have a server `server C` which is located within the IP range and the only thing blocking `server A` from `server C` is a firewall (which I have access to). It must be possible to create a hole in the firewall between `server A` and `server C`, but my question is:

**How do I relay the request from `server A` to `server B` via `server C`?**

I need the response from `server B` to get back to `server A` also :)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take a look at WCF; perhaps creating an intermediate service on server C that mediates between the other 2.

Comment: It seems like WCF is a good solution so far. Thanks for forcing me into trying WCF ;)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look a HTTP Proxies, there are lots of open-source ones but I haven't had any experience working with them so can't recommend one.

Failing that, look into socket programming (http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/socketsincsharp.aspx) - you could write a socket-based interface between server A and server C, server C will then send the request on and marshall the response back to server A.